# How can I change the link text of a PDF Link with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I want to make a link in a PDF file that when clicked on changes the text of the link.  In HTML with JavaScript you can do that with the `innerHTML` property of the link.  Is there an analog in JavaScript for PDF?

Comment: Is the link in the PDF or is it on a webpage?

Comment: @epascarello: it's in the PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is *no*, and the reason has to do with the specifications of links in PDF vs. HTML.  In an HTML file a link is part of the document tree, and the text of the link is one of its children.  In a PDF file a link is a "hot" rectangle on the page that does something when the user clicks in it.  The link may surround some text but as far as the document is concerned that's a coincidence.

The way I found to have dynamic data in a PDF file is to use form fields.  Those can change their contents on mouse events.  By default form fields look different than the regular document text but in my case that was not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter PDF files with JavaScript. :(

Comment: I don't actually want to alter the file.  I want the file to be dynamic in that what is displayed depends on a mouse click.  Both the original text and the replacement text would be in the file someplace.

Comment: JavaScript is not able to access the contents of a PDF in any way -- at least in a web browser. (You can do it in Adobe Acrobat.)

Comment: I do want the JavaScript to be within the PDF, using Acrobat (actually, using LaTeX), not in a web browser.